# How to smooth every plot in GNUplot?

Tags: automation, gnuplot, smoothing

I have a script where I do a lot of plots of a couple of data files. Now, I want to smoothen the curves with `smooth csplines`.

Unfortunately, I would have to manually add this to every single plot command, which is neither beautiful, nor very elegant (and harder to maintain).

So my question is: Is there a way to `set` something somehow or any workaround so that I automatically `smooth` every plot?

Thank you guys in advance,
BUFU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot set the smoothing globally. In order to improve maintenability you can use macros to define the options in one place an use them for every `plot`:

```
set macros
opt = "smooth csplines"
plot 'a' @opt
```